# Black screen while installing Debian

Tags: installation, debian

I tried installing Debian with a netinstall CD-ROM on my custom-built PC. Everything is going fine until I choose any of the install options because then the screen turns black and I get no graphical feedback at all. The screen itself seems to get information though because it doesn't go into stand-by mode. The disk drive doesn't show any activity though. Does anyone know what could cause this and/or how I could keep it from happening?

**Specs**

- Processor: Intel i5-2500K @ 3.30GHz
- Mainboard: AsRock Z77 Extreme 4
- RAM: 2x 4GB (DDR3-1600), 1x 8GB (DDR3-1600)
- Graphics: GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 660 Ti

EDIT: I just tried installing debian again (using "Graphic install") after I set the SATA mode from AHCI to IDE. This is what I've got:

```
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x52 SAct 0x0 SErr 0xffffffff action 0xe frozen
ata1: SError: { RecovData RecovComm UnrecovData Persist Proto HostInt PHYRdyChg PHYInt CommWake 10B8B Dispar BadCRC Handshk LinkSeq TrStaTrns UnrecFIS DevExch }
ata1.00: failed command: IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE
ata1.00: cmd a1/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 6 pio 512
in res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x56 (ATA bus error)
ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
```

EDIT 2: I don't know why, I don't even know how that should be a problem, but apparently this error message is connected to me having a DVD-RW drive connected to my mainboard. I managed to install Debian Jessie on another way but every time I tried to start it up (with the DVD-RW drive connected), I got exactly the same error message (with the exception that `ata1` was changed to `ata7` for some reason). I have no idea what I am doing wrong at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 guessable reasons:

1. Compatibility problems with graphics driver used by installer - when installer tries to find out possible desktop resolutions and hangs. To avoid that, just install in Text Mode.
2. Broken DVD image, DVD disk, DVD-RW or hard disk. Try to install from another DVD, recorded on different computer.

Comment: As much as I'd like to say that helped, it didn't. The problem is not with the DVD itself but rather with the _drive_ that reads it. I just installed Debian Jessie via USB (which worked out fine) but at first it crashed again while the drive was connected. I disconnected it and then it worked fine.

Comment: 2c - DVD-RW, like I said.

Comment: Apart from when I want to install Debian Jessie with it, the drive works fine.